# How to get PANDAS EWMA results to match online EWMA calculator results?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [345,373,373,359,376,376,413,383,467,464,540,628,545,631,617,607,590,576,565,617]})
ewm = df['values'].ewm(span=7, adjust=False).mean()
ewm
```

The result is:

```
0     345.000000
1     352.000000
2     357.250000
3     357.687500
4     362.265625
5     365.699219
6     377.524414
7     378.893311
8     400.919983
9     416.689987
10    447.517490
11    492.638118
12    505.728588
13    537.046441
14    557.034831
15    569.526123
16    574.644592
17    574.983444
18    572.487583
19    583.615687
```

But online calculator (https://goodcalculators.com/exponential-moving-average-calculator) using the same input values and period (or span, 7) gives these results:

```
363.667,366,367.75,365.563,368.172,370.129,380.847,381.385,402.789,418.092,448.569,493.427,506.32,537.49,557.367,569.776,574.832,575.124
```

Why are the results different?

How can the code be modified to give results matching the online calculator?